# how to make `.inputrc` keybindings to work on commands that are using `read`?

Tags: bash, readline, inputrc

I have this snippet in my `.inputrc` to map `jj` as `enter/return`.

```
 "jj": "\C-M"
```

It works well but not for commands that are using `read`, for example entering passwords.

How can I make this to also work on `read` commands?

Comment: `read -e` enables readline editing on the input.

Comment: @meuh Thanks for the feedback.. it works, but how about for commands that I dont have control to? like commands that accepts passwords like `su`?

Comment: You cannot make all commands use the readline library. You can prefix some commands with `rlwrap` which will do readline editing before sending on the line, however your best solution is to use something like `tmux` in your terminal to handle all input, using its set of bindings.

Comment: @meuh iguess its really impossible.. can you elaborate more on handling input using tmux?

Comment: Since tmux sits between you and the terminal emulator you are using, it can  replace anything you type by anything else before passing it on. However, handling your example of "jj" is not really going to be easy to implement in tmux as it is very much oriented to handling only one character at a time, or a special "prefix" character then a single character.  Perhaps, if you have some programming experience, you could instead consider using the `expect` command. It can look at the input for patterns and act on them or pass the data on. Look in its man page for the example for cmd `interact`.